# How to instantiate MyList object

Tags: java

I saw this code in the textbook "Java by Dissection" but don't understand what it does exactly. The textbook barely explained anything regarding this code, besides for saying it implements a nested class. But I want to understand what it actually does.

The reason I want to understand this code is because I was trying to create a main that would declare/instantiate an object of the MyList class with the values 1-10. Then add a few numbers to the top and delete a few from anywhere I wanted. Could anyone help me with this?

The main part I don't understand is nested class - ListedElement.

```
public class MyList {
  private ListElement head, tail; //Forward declaration
  void add(Object value) {
    if (tail != null) {
      tail.next = new ListElement(value);
      tail = tail.next;
    }
    else {
      head = tail = new ListElement(value);
    }
  }
  Object remove() 
  {
    assert head != null; // don't remove on empty list
    Object result = head.value;
    head = head.next;
    if (head == null) { //was that the last?
      tail = null;
    }
    return result;
  }
  //Nested class needed only in the implementation of MyList
  private class ListElement {
    ListElement(Object value) {this.value = value;}
    Object value;
    ListElement next; //defaults to null as desired
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a linked list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: It's *really* hard to explain something to someone without knowing a little bit about what they know / terms they're familiar with / etc.  Do you have specific questions?

Comment: jedwards, I know a good amount of C++ and am just starting in Java. I was trying to implement a main to this program that instantiated a MyList object and put the values 1-10 in it. Then added a few numbers to the top and deleted a few numbers from anywhere. But I realized I don't really understand this class all that much so wanted help with that.

Comment: Do one thing edit your post by adding comments against each line according to your understanding of what each one is doing.

Comment: Tailored the question a bit to show what I really wasn't understanding and what I wanted to do once I understood. Mark S gave a good explanation.

Comment: @TomG - Thank you for pointing it out.  Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the basics: MyList is a class, which is a unit of code in Java.  Inside this class you have:

- methods: add, remove
- an inner class: ListElement
- some fields: head, tail, both of type ListElement

In any class, "stuff" generally happens when you call methods.  Here, there are two, both of which do what they say they do.

The best way to explain it may be to actually demonstrate how you might use it in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyList anInstance = new MyList(); // creates an instance of the MyList class
    // note that at this point, the instance is created, but because there is no constructor method, the fields (head, tail) are both null

    String someValue = "A list element";
    anInstance.add(someValue); // add an element to the list
    // if you step through the add method, you'll see that the value coming in is a String ("A list element"), but nothing has been initialized yet (head, tail are both null)
    // So you'd go to the "else" bit of the logic in the add method, which initializes the head and tail element to the same object that you passed in.  So now your list contains one item ("A list element");

    String anotherValue = "Another value";
    anInstance.add(anotherValue); // add a second element to the list
    // now the path through the add method is different, because your head and tail elements have been initialized, so set the tail.next value to the new element, and then have tail be this new value.
    // so the head is "A list element" and the tail is "Another value" at this point, and the head's next field is "Another value" (this is the linking part of a linked list)

    // from here, you could add more elements, or you could remove elements.  The remove method is pretty straight forward as well -- it removes from the front of the list (note the part of the code that returns the head, and then updates the head value to point to the next item in the list.

}
```

Hope this gets you started on what's going on here, and by all means ask more questions if any of this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear and definitely helps me understand this. How would I change the `remove` method to allow me to `remove` from anywhere in the list I wanted? For example I pass a number to `remove` and at that spot `remove` would delete that value.

Comment: @RichieMiz - By "*I pass a **number***" do you mean something like array **index**? If so, I believe it can't be done without at least implementing [`iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface and thus making `MyClass` [`iteratable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).  If you need such functionality in real life applications use one of Java [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: I would also like to print out this the contents of `anInstance` but am not sure how to do that.

Comment: To print an object in a meaningful way you need to override its [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method. Then you can use [`System.out.println()`](http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/) method to print it.