# How for-each loop knows where to start?

Tags: java, foreach, iterator

**Iterator** is guaranteed to have the following methods:

- hasNext()
- next()
- remove (*optional*)

When `for-each` loop iterates through `iterable` class objects, how does it know what object to **start** with? The above methods provide clear path forward, but what points to the starting element?

`For-each` guarantees to iterate through **all** relevant objects.  Depending on a class and its `next()` implementation it could be vitally important where to start (consider `forward linked list` or any other implementation that has a `root` element).

How does it work?

If my question does not make sense please explain why.

Comment: It uses whatever `next()` returns on the first iteration...

Comment: The iterator you obtain from the container is initialized to the start.

Comment: You define where to start in the `Iterator` implementation. For example, for `List`s, you have a *straight* iterator that goes from first element to last, and a reverse iterator that goes from last element to first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  - What about my **own custom iterator**? Where exactly the starting  point logic should be implemented?  Like in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992132/how-to-make-a-class-which-is-not-a-descendant-of-collection-compatible-with) you were helping me with.

Comment: In that case, your iterator will start with the first `Thing` you can access. Then, it depends how you want to navigate through that tree. As noted in comments, you can implement prefix, infix or postfix traversal.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - 
I'm very sorry for being so thick, but I am still not sure that I got it. Do I need to preserve the `root` (in my case `Thing` with `null` *previous* variable) object myself and make sure that iterator method returns iterator instance that points to this root?

Comment: This depends on the implementation. As I've posted in comments, you can do this using a `Queue<Thing>`or another data structure to do the navigation before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the spec:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

What's officially called the **enhanced `for` statement** (`for(E e: Iterable<E> iterable)`) is translated by the compiler into the equivalent of the following code:

```
E e;
for(Iterator<E> it = iterable.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    e = it.next();
    // contents of your for loop
}
```

The behavior of the loop is exactly as if you'd written it with an explicit `Iterator`, so the "starting point" of the enhanced `for` loop is wherever `iterable.iterator()` would have started anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at `ArrayList`'s implementation of an `Iterator`, the `Itr` inner class.

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
    ...
}
```

`cursor` gets initialized to `0` by default. You use `cursor` to access the elements in the `ArrayList` object's backing array (it's an inner class, it has access to that field).

Similar logic applies for other implementations of `Iterator`. It always depends on the underlying data structure. As another example, a `Set` is not supposed to have an ordering, but it does implement `Iterator`. A decision has to be made as to where the iterator starts.

Answer (score 0):

foreach is a shorthand for for loop starting from first till last.

Comment: What defines "*first*" and "*last*" for custom class that is **not** derived from Java `Collection`?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your collection.

If your collection is a List (`ArrayList` or `LinkedList` usually), then the iterator will go in list order according to how they were inserted.

If it is a Map or Set, it is very hard to predict the ordering of its members. If you are using a Map or Set, you should not count on any sort of predictable ordering, in fact, because it doesn't match those collections' purposes. However, `LinkedHashMap` or `LinkedHashSet` can be used if you need a specific order but also need the functionality of a Map or Set.

Comment: What if I do not have a collection but simply a class that implements `Iterable`?